# How to get a screenshot and show it to the user after the audit page speed?

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, lighthouse

I recently working with API page speed google, Now I want to show thumbnail screenshot after the audit. But I don't know how to get a screenshot from the user's site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When API returns JSON has the lighthouseResult object that includes audits object, you can find thumbnails array in the screenshot-thumbnails.

In this case, I've used:

```
lighthouseResult.audits['screenshot-thumbnails'].details.items[9].data;
```

Also, you can get final-screenshot :

```
lighthouseResult.audits['final-screenshot'].details.data;
```

Notice: data is base64.